# Is this an official download mirror?

Tags: tails, connection, server, source-code, server-administration

Is this an official download mirror of the Tails?

http://quantum-mirror.hu/mirrors/pub/tails/stable/

http://quantum-mirror.hu

Comment: It does not appear to be an official mirror. But remember to always verify your download regardless of what mirror you get it from: https://tails.boum.org/install/download/index.en.html#openpgp

Comment: It is very interesting, because I start this download in Tails 4.12 (the earlier version of the Tails, I tried to download the new 4.14) and a used obsf4 bridges to connect the network! Yes I know that unfree to download with Tails, it was a test!   I'm a betatester and I'm experinced some interesting thing in the last days when I was used the Tails. The most interesting thing that I'm on Hungary! Accordingly "they" can recognize me  :-)

Comment: To verify the downloaded .iso? Sorry but on this mirror also are pgp keys, false keys for the false files. If this is an false mirror than the pgp keys will be goods  :-) Earlier I doesn't know this mirror I started everytime the download on the https://tails.boum.org the .iso and the pgp keys also.  :-)

Comment: Summarized: I started to download the new Tails. I booted my computer from an USB key with Tails. I made this USB key with cloning for an DVD wrote Tails 4.12. Before I started the Tails I chose bridge connection. I'm already collected obsf4 bridges from here: https://bridges.torproject.org/options      When the Tails already started I switched on my modem and when the Tails asked I copyed the bridges and after a short time the connection was effected. After I started the download what is failed.....with the over mentioned "mirror".

Comment: Accordingly: my traffic across an obsf4 bridge is hijackable - avertable (sorry because my english knowledge) somehow  :-(  My modem is vulnerable this is true and maybe already fleshad this is my side so far I'm already taken out  every vulnerable hardware (whats I knew) from my machine. But what is on the side of the Tails?

Comment: I'm curious and I'm ready to help for anybody to find the source of this error. I'm waiting for an request.

Comment: Don't worry I'm not a thug, the beta testing is a free time facility for me. This is not the first case that I found some "bug"  :-)  but I'm not a professional rather I'm amateur bug hunter (I made it for free not for money).

Answer (score 0):

at 8-8-2023 i found 25 tails mirrors with google: "Index of" tails

go to /tails/stable/ this is the right directory

verify your download at:

https://tails.net/install/download-iso/index.de.html        (new)

or

https://tails.boum.org/install/download-iso/index.de.html   (old)

mirrors:

https://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/tails.boum.org/tails/stable/tails-amd64-5.14/tails-amd64-5.14.iso

https://mirror.ihost.md/tails/stable/tails-amd64-5.14/tails-amd64-5.14.iso

https://tails.tetaneutral.net/stable/tails-amd64-5.14/tails-amd64-5.14.iso

https://194.71.11.163/tails/stable/tails-amd64-5.14/tails-amd64-5.14.iso

http://194.8.197.22/tails/tails/stable/tails-amd64-5.14/tails-amd64-5.14.iso

to update tails via tor on weekends is nearly impossible